# UML: Self-defined data types as attributes in classes / when adding an attribute to a class is allowed

Tags: uml, relationship, custom-data-type, multiplicity

Similar questions have been asked, but this does not fully address my problem:

- [Object as data attribute of class in Class diagram UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335314/object-as-data-attribute-of-class-in-class-diagram-uml)
- [When to use an attribute (property) instead of an association/aggregation/composition when drawing a UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557758/when-to-use-an-attribute-property-instead-of-an-association-aggregation-compos)

I am having problem with the following statement made by my teacher:

1. "You can only have in-built or custom-defined data types, as types of attributes in your classes. For other attributes multiplicity defines quantity and whether it is obligatory." (fair enough)

Let's assume the following description:

[...]Each operation holds a sequence of tasks to be executed on a required quality level - for each task there is an associated quality level selected from the list of available quality levels for this task.[...] (Operation holds number of other attributes as well).

Now I have drawn the following "class diagram":
[image: class diagram]

Questions:

1. Can I have self-defined data types as part of my class diagram (as a class) or can these be used only as attributes within other classes?
2. If these data types can be used only as attributes, then I do not know how I can mark the fact that the collection is ordered and unique other by adding this attribute to a class - which - according to my teacher - is not allowed - because then I would be having a collection of a type which is neither an in-built type or self-defined type as an attribute.
3. According to my knowledge adding an attribute to a class and specifying this collection is ordered is the only way of marking such property and cannot be achieved with multiplicity.

Can someone please shed a bit of light on what is the proper notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can have as many self defined `Datatype` on your diagram as you want, but beware: there's a difference between `Datatype` and a `Class`
2. UML allows to use both `Classes` and `Datatypes` to be the type of your `Attribute`.
3. In UML `Attributes` and `Associations` are often interchangeable. The defining characteristics of both are defined in `Property`, which includes multiplicity and other constraints such as `{ordered}`

However there are best practices in use that your teacher may be referring too. It is quite sensible to use attributes for relations to `Datatypes` and associations for relations to `Classes`. For more information about this see [UML Best Practice: Attribute or Association](http://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/)